# Writing System.Out.Println into text file

Tags: java

I need to write those System.out.printlns into a text file, but I have no idea how this could happen so I need some help from someone advanced.

```
  System.out.println("You have have entered "+EnteredNumbers+ " numbers!");
  System.out.println("You have have entered "+Positive+ " Positive numbers!");
  System.out.println("The Average of the Positive Numebers is "+AveragePositive+ "!");
  System.out.println("You have have entered "+Negative+ " Negative numbers!");
  System.out.println("The Sum of the Negative numbers is "+NegativeSum+ "!");
```

And here is the whole code:

```
import java.io.*; 

public class Nums { 
  public static void main(String args[]) 
    throws IOException 
  { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    String str;
    int EnteredNumbers = -1;
    int Positive = 0;
    int Negative = 0;
    int NegativeSum = 0;
    int PositiveSum = 0; 
    double AveragePositive = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter '0' to quit."); 
    System.out.println("Enter Numbers: "); 
   try{
    do { 
      EnteredNumbers++;
      str = br.readLine();
      int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
      if (num>0)
      {
        Positive++;
        PositiveSum+=num;
      }
      else if (num<0)
      {
        Negative++;
        NegativeSum+=num;
      }
       } 
    while(!str.equals("0")); 
      AveragePositive = (double)PositiveSum/(double)Positive;  
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+EnteredNumbers+ " numbers!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Positive+ " Positive numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Average of the Positive Numebers is "+AveragePositive+ "!");
      System.out.println("You have have entered "+Negative+ " Negative numbers!");
      System.out.println("The Sum of the Negative numbers is "+NegativeSum+ "!");

      }
    catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Format!");
    }  
} 
}
```

I am a beginner and I would love to get some help!

Comment: Do you means you need to run your program with `java Nums > file.out` Or that you need to write to a file, or that you really need anything written to System.out without knowing this is writing to a file?

Comment: I need to write to a file

Comment: Tutorials on the net about; for instance see [here](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` that writes to the standard output. You need to create a `FileOutputStream` and decorates it with `PrintStream` (or better `FileWriter` with `PrintWriter`):

```
File file = new File("C:/file.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
pw.println("Hello World");
pw.close();
```

---

**Also see:**

- [Which is the best way to create file and write to it in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26381181/597657)

Comment: I tried that but it looks I am doing something wrong... Can you adjust my code so I can try it out?

Comment: @DanielaGocheva Replace `System.out.println` with `pw.println` in your code for the lines you want to write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use setOut() method for filewrite with System.out.println(); after call setOut() whenever use System.out.println() then the method sop will be print on file or whichever you give in setOut() method

Comment: setOut() method change the default PrintStream Object.

Answer (score 0):

This is 2014. So there is java.nio.file.

Therefore:

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("first string here");
list.add("other string");
// etc etc
```

Then:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/write/to");

Files.write(path, list, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

And [don't use `File`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks).